# Let $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable, satisfy $f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)$ for each $x\in[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Question: 4. Let $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable, satisfy $f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)$ for each $x\in[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Find all such function $f$.

My solution: It is given that $f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x), \forall x\in[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Observe that $f(x)\equiv 0$ is surely a solution.

Claim: $f(x)\equiv 0$ is the only solution.

Proof: For the sake of contradiction let us assume that there exists a function $f$ such that it is not identically equal to $0$ and satisfies all the conditions of the problem. Now given this and since we have $f(a)=f(b)=0$, we are sure that there are at least two roots of $f$ in $[a,b]$. This helps us in concluding that $\exists p,q\in[a,b]$, such that $p<q$, $f(p)=f(q)=0$ and $f(x)\neq 0,\forall x\in(p,q).$

WLOG, let us assume that $f(x)>0, \forall x\in(p,q).$ Now since $f$ is continuous on $[p,q]$, thus by Extreme value theorem $f$ must attain a maximum and minimum value in $[p,q]$. Now it is trivial to observe that the minimum value of $f(x)$ in $[p,q]$ is $0$ and the maximum value is some positive real number $M$ attained at some point $c\in(p,q)$. Now since $f$ is differentiable at $c$ we must have $f'(c)=0$. Thus we have $f(c)=f'(c)+f''(c)=f''(c).$ Now since $c\in(p,q)\implies f(c)>0\implies f''(c)>0.$ Now since $f''(c)>0$, thus by double-derivative test we can conclude that $f$ attains a local minimum at $x=c$, which is a clear contradiction.

Thus there does not exist a function $f$ such that it is not identically equal to $0$ and satisfies all the conditions of the problem. Hence the only solution to the problem is $f(x)\equiv 0$.

Is this solution correct? And is there a better solution than this?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: I don't see the conclusion of your first paragraph. How do you make sure that the zeroes of $f$ don't accumulate?

Comment: @Thorgott even if the zeros accumulate the conclusion would be correct, unless the set of zeros is dense. If the set of zeros is dense and $f$ is continuous, then $f=0$.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply your argument directly on $[a, b]$ instead of applying it on $[p, q] $. Let $f$ take some positive value in $(a, b) $ and then $f$ attains maximum at $c\in(a, b) $ with $f(c) >0,f'(c)=0,f''(c)>0$ and then $c$ is a strict local minimum. Contradiction! Done!! I wonder why you thought of getting to $p, q$.

---

Your solution as it stands is fully rigorous even though the existence of $p, q$ is not justified in detail. Their existence follows by continuity of $f$. +1 for coming up with the solution on your own.

Comment: There is still a contradiction but the premises are weaker than previously. It proves only there is no positive max (before the condition $f>0$ implied $f=0$ directly), but what about a negative min. Of course same argument works, and now $f$ has no min nor max, so it is constant.

Comment: @zwim: I left the case for minimum as obvious as it can be given using similar argument. In general even in an exam, one must not force an examinee to give trivial and obvious details in full. Just mentioning them is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In the present case the ODE is solvable, you get $f(x)=Ae^{-\phi x}+Be^{x/\phi}=e^{-\phi x}(A+Be^{kx})$, in fact we do not really care for the real values of roots, just that they are real.

Since exponential is positive we need to annulate twice $A+Be^{kx}$ which is not 
possible by convexity unless $A=B=0$.

---

I kind of follow your proof but like Thorgott, I find the conclusion of first paragraph a bit too direct.

Maybe something like, $f$ continuous and $f\neq 0$ so there exist an interval $I\subset (a,b)$ such that $f\neq 0$ on $I$ and now take $\begin{cases}p=\sup\{x\le\inf I\mid f(x)=0\}\\q=\inf\{x\ge\sup I\mid f(x)=0\}\end{cases}$

So that it is clear you just "extend" $I$ to the biggest open interval on which $f$ is of constant sign.

The second paragraph is ok.